# How to handle iPhone screen sizes with MergAV

Tags: ios, external, livecode

I'm trying to build a small iOS app using MergAV to scan QRCodes. The only thing that troubles me is that if I create the app based on iPhone 5 screen size everything works OK. Even on the bigger screens! But If I start out with an iPhone 6 sized stack I need to add:

```
set the fullscreenmode of this stack to "ShowAll"
```

Otherwise the stack will be to big on an iPhone 6 or 7. This is strange in itself but manageable. After the line above my stack tells that the scaleFactor is 1 and the systemPixelScale is 2 (as expected) but when I set the rect of the "camera" via:

```
mergAVCamSet "rect",the rect of grc "cam"
```

the camera doesn't get the correct rect. It is offset slightly down-left and is higher than the original rect. If I on the other hand query the rect of the graphic and the rect of the camera via `mergAVCamGet("rect")` the first three numbers are the same but the last (bottom value) differs and the cam actually have a lower number!

Is this a bug? Something I should know? Something I can workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
function realDeviceSize pParam
   local nX, nY
   put item 3 of the screenRect / item 3 of the effective rect of this stack into nX
   put item 4 of the screenRect / item 4 of the effective rect of this stack into nY
   put the round of (item 1 of pParam * nX) into item 1 of pParam
   put the round of (item 2 of pParam * nY) into item 2 of pParam
   put the round of (item 3 of pParam * nX) into item 3 of pParam
   put the round of (item 4 of pParam * nY) into item 4 of pParam
   return pParam
end realDeviceSize

on preOpenCard
   put realDeviceSize(the rect of image "iRectangle") into tCameraRect
end preOpenCard
```

Comment: Please add some explanation rather than only a piece of code.